# Access nested arrays and dictionaries generated by JSON-framework iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, json-framework

I'm using a Google API to return some JSON, which i have converted to their Objective C types using the JSON-framework (Stig B - Google Code).

I now have structures like this:

```
responseData
    results
        [0]
            title = "Stack Overflow"
    cursor
```

How can i access the nested array `results` to get at the `title` value (dictionary i'm guessing)?

I have tried this but no success:

```
    for (NSString *key in [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"responseData"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",key);
        for (NSString *element in [key valueForKey:@"results"]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",element);   
        }
    }
```

The outer loop will print out the names of the arrays `results` and `cursor` so that works, but for the inner loop, I get a `not key value coding compliant` error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSLog([jsonObjects description])` to see the contents and structure of your dictionary. 
To browse to your "results" array and its contents you can use the following (or similar) code:

```
NSDictionary* responseDict = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"responseData"]; // Get your dictionary
NSArray* resultsArray = [responseDict objectForKey:@"results"]; 
for (NSDictionary* internalDict in resultsArray)
    for (NSString *key in [internalDict allKeys])
       NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", key, [internalDict objectForKey:key];
```